# Community C++ plugin - advantages or stable against the Sonarqube C++ plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I understand that there is the Community C++ plugin available for C++ code to be analysed and there is a plugin from sonar which is not free. I did use the community C++ plugin however i would like to know what is the difference between these two plugins.

1. Are the set of rules different in both of these plugins.
2. How stable is Community C++ plugin - and will it have or capture the results or technical debt etc similar to the Sonar C++ plugin.

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Answers to this are going to be primarily opinion-based - you're basically asking to compare 2 different products.

Comment: In order to add to @Dinesh-SonarSourceTeam comment as sonarqube C++ plugin is a commercial plugin you should reach out commercial support to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

the c++ community plugin is stable at version 0.9.4 with almost complete support for c++11 and partial c++14. You can see the complete list of features [here](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Description---Features)

the community plugin relies mostly on external analyzers and its highly extendable and you can use any external tool given that the input format is followed see [here](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Extending-the-code-analysis), it supports by default RATS, VERA, CPPCHECK and PClint (give that you generate reports outside analysis).

additionally to this it contains about 30 own [rules](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/tree/master/cxx-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/cxx/checks), that can be found in many of the plugins that exist for sonar (those run during the analysis). the C++ plugin provided by SonarSource supports [CPPCheck](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#languages=cpp%7Crepositories=cpp) and 196 own rules that run during analysis see [here](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#languages=cpp%7Crepositories=cpp)

Comment: 11:16:30.506 WARN  - [sonar.cxx.forceIncludes:1]: cannot find the sources for '"VS10Macros.h"'
11:16:30.643 WARN  - [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sonar_OnlineBackoOffice/workspace/INCLUDE/Activity_PL.h:4]: cannot find the sources for '#include "onlinedlgclient.h"'
11:16:30.646 WARN  - [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sonar_OnlineBackoOffice/workspace/INCLUDE/Activity_PL.h:5]: cannot find the sources for '#include "autoreg_dlg.h"'

Comment: 11:16:31.057 ERROR - Unable to parse file: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sonar_OnlineBackoOffice/workspace/INCLUDE/COSServices.h
11:16:31.057 ERROR - Parse error at line 51 column 16:

   46: extern "C" {
   47: 
   48: 
   49: 
   50: 
  -->  __declspec ( dllimport )INT_stdcallFARPASCALCOSLOGON(LPSTRName,LPSTRPsw,LPSTR AppId, LPSTR gs_COSSys);
   52: __declspec ( dllimport )INT_stdcallFARPASCALSend_SMS(LPSTR

Comment: Getting this error during building the sonar job in Jenkins.But the job is running successful. And in Sonar report its showing 0 issues. So what need to be done to resolve this issue.

This is the sonar.properites file content.

sonar.projectKey=OnlineBackOffice
sonar.projectName=OnlineBackOffice project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.cxx.suffixes.sources=.cxx,.cpp,.cc,.c
sonar.cxx.suffixes.headers=.hxx,.hpp,.hh,.h
sonar.cxx.include_directories=include
sonar.cxx.forceIncludes=VS10Macros.h
sonar.sourceEncoding=ISO-8859-1
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=c++
sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath=*-*.xml

Comment: try and follow the instructions here: https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Detect-and-fix-parsing-errors if you run windows, you could give a try to this wrapper https://github.com/jmecsoftware/sonar-cxx-msbuild-tasks/releases/tag/1.9.1 and https://github.com/jmecsoftware/sonar-cxx-msbuild-tasks